# How to get the count number for each category

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to get the count summary for each category in R Studio. 
Here's a reproducible example:

```
column_1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D")
column_2 <- c("YES","NO","YES","YES","YES","NO","YES","YES","YES","NO","YES","YES","YES","NO")
df <- data.frame(column_1,column_2)
```

I want the result to be like this: count the number of "YES" and "NO" for each category A B C D. Please see below picture:

[image]

Comment: @d.b thank you so much! This works! I wanted to store the result "result <- table(df)" into a data frame by "result <- data.frame(result)". But that would give me another result in data frame that is completely different from "table(df)". Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, column_1 ~ paste0(column_2, "_count"), length)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go:

```
library(tidyverse)

column_1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D")
column_2 <- c("YES","NO","YES","YES","YES","NO","YES","YES","YES","NO","YES","YES","YES","NO")
df <- data.frame(column_1,column_2)

df %>% group_by(column_1) %>%count(column_2) %>% spread(column_2, n)
```

I have a hard time remembering the spread function which helps go from long data to wide data.  This website is so helpful for that: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/